# When is a Banach Algebra $C^\star$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I know that if there are enough Hermitian elements in a Banach algebra, then the Banach algebra is stellar. In particular, I'm interested in the two spaces $B(L^1(S^1,\Sigma,\mu))$ the space of bounded linear operators on Lebesgue integrable functions of the circle and $B(ba(\Sigma))$ the space of bounded linear operators on finite, finitely-additive Borel measures. I know about the results that having enough Hermitian elements is sufficient, but I'm not quite sure how to apply them.

The issue comes up because I am trying to bound the inverse of a Hermitian element in terms of its spectral radius. From my reading, we have an equality for $C^\star$ algebras and an inequality for Banach algebras.

Comment: Please link to a reference to the results about "enough Hermitian elements". This seems pretty neat!

Comment: Cross-posted at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175550/when-is-a-banach-algebra-stellar

Comment: I stole that phrase from the paper "The Spectral Theorem in Banach Algebras" S. Plafker (link below). From reading the references therein, if $H\subset B$ is the set of Hermitian elements in your Banach algebra, B, H+iH=B implies B is isometrically isomorphic to a $C^\star$ algebra.

http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ13_01%2FS0017089500035758a.pdf&code=518bf602adb31bbe90aecae20ceafeb1

Comment: Maybe it will be enough if your algebra is symmetric? What exactly you want from your spectral radius?

Comment: And, what involution do you consider on $B(L^1)$?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a bound of $\|x^{-1}\|$ in terms of the spectral radius. I know $\rho(x^{-1})$ and that $x$ is Hermitian. If $B(L^1)$ is $C^\star$, I have $\|x^{-1}\|=\rho(x^{-1})$. If it is not, I have $\|x^{-1}\|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\rho(x^{-1})$. 

My understanding for the involution is that if $H+iH=B$, we can write any element $x\in B$ as $x=a+ib$ where $a,\,b\in H$. In that case, $x^\star=a-ib$. 

I know my $x$ is Hermitian since $\|\exp[i\alpha x]\|=1$ for real $\alpha$, so I don't need to know the structure of the involution, just that it exists.

Comment: Hi Daniel, your link didn't work. I had no idea there were results like this out there at all. Cool question!

Comment: @Jon, did searching for the title I listed bring anything up? If not, I can email you that paper (it is publicly available) and some other references including a reference for the inverse norm inequality.

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't manage to write anything concrete, but here are some impressions of your problem. You wouldn't need to know the involution IF you knew that a good one exists. But I doubt very much that $B(L^1)$ could be renormed as a $C^*$-algebra. $L^1$ itself cannot, for example.

Comment: At the same time, it may be possible to prove that $B(L^1)$ is a symmetric Banach algebra, i.e. the spectrum of every selfadjoint element is real. $L^1(S^1)$ is symmetric (while for some non-abelian groups it is not). If you prove that, then you will have $\|a\|\le \rho(a^*a)^{1/2}$ for every $a$.

Comment: @Yulia: When you say selfadjoint, do you mean something to the effect that for every $A\in B(L^1)$ $A\Big|_{L^\infty}=A^\star$ where $A^\star:L^\infty\to L^\infty$? The operator I have is self-adjoint in that sense, so I have tried to go down that road unsuccessfully. That inequality would give me what I need, I believe.

Comment: @Jon Some comments since some of Daniel's terminology may not be familiar to everyone: an element $x$ of a unital Banach algebra is *defined* to be Hermitian if $\Vert e^{itx} \Vert=1$ for all real $t$ -- this can probably be found in Bonsall & Duncan -- and the result that Daniel was referring to is the Vidav-Palmer theorem.

Comment: @Daniel: my gut feeling is that you may be better off looking for a smaller closed subalgebra of $B(L^1)$ which contains your given operator, and trying to get results there. For instance, there are Banach spaces X which are not Hilbert space, but come with a natural group action, such that the closed subalgebra of B(X) generated by the translation operators is isometrically isomorphic to a C-star algebra

Comment: @Yulia: can't we take a self-adjoint element of $\ell^1(F_2)$ which has non-real spectrum, and then regard it as an operator on $B(\ell^1(F_2))$? Something similar could be done for $L^1$ by looking at a non-discrete non-hermitian group.

Comment: I cannot access to the reference given by Yemon. 
But, if you consult the book by A. A. Kirillov 
"Elements of the theory of representations", he does 
(certainly on the basis of Gelfand seminars), the 
Gelfand transform for arbitrary Banach algebras 
(paragraph 4.2) and the fact that it does not 
see nilpotent elements (problem 10 and example 3). 
Now, my question is 
"If you consider the (commutative) algebra $R$ generated by 
your operator" (the closure of the values of polynomials of your operator). Is there something known about the characters of it?     

Comment: Or, which is equivalent, about the spectral reconstruction of your operator (I am pretty shure that this point can be found in the H. K"onig reference, but I am travelling in Asia and cannot access). 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question posed in your first paragraph (which I think is asking for more than you need, and more importantly, more than you can really hope for). However, for the specific purpose outlined in your second paragraph, the following paper might be helpful:

> H. König, A functional calculus for Hermitian elements of complex Banach algebras.
>   [Arch. Math. (Basel) 28 (1977), no. 4, 422–430.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01223945)

IIRC, one has a C^1-functional calculus for Hermitian elements in Banach algebras (this is proved by taking the Fourier transform of your C^1 function after introducing a smooth cutoff outside the support of the spectrum of your Hermitian element). So if the spectrum of your $x$ is contained in $[a,b]$ for $0 \lt a$ then $\Vert x^{-1}\Vert$ should **hopefully** be bounded above by some universal constant times $a^{-2} = \rho(x^{-1})^2$. CAVEAT: I have not checked this in detail!

**Update:** I've just remembered that there are theorems to the effect that if $E$ is a Banach space, $A(E)$ the algebra of approximable operators, and $X$ is a reflexive Banach space, then an injective algebra homomorphism $A(E)\to B(X)$ must arise from some embedding of $E$ into $X$ as a closed, complemented subspace. In particular, if there is an injective HM $B(E) \to B(H)$ for some Hilbert space then $E=H$. So the two Banach algebras mentioned at the start of your question can't possibly be $C^\ast$-algebras.

Comment: Thank for your insight. I haven't looked into the theorems you reference in your update, but I believe you that that road is not very productive. I was never able to get a strong enough bound on that universal constant for the the bound to be of much use to me. However, I have since been able to observe that the operator I'm working with is a perturbation of a resolvent positive operator and get some good results from there.

Comment: @Yemon, do you have by chance any reference for this theorem about homomorphisms into $B(X)$?

Comment: @Slavoj I found this as Proposition 3.3.14 in the PhD thesis of Matthew Daws ( http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~mdaws/notes.html ) but apparently it may be folklore.